# JSR-303 Type Checking Before Binding

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

model....

```
@Digits(integer=5, fraction=0, message="The value must be numeric and less than five digits")
private int value;
```

beans file....

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

controller....

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/save.htm", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView saveSection(@Valid @ModelAttribute Section section, BindingResult result) {
     if(result.hasErrors())   {
         return new ModelAndView("admin/editSection", "section", section);
     }
```

How do I restrict "value" to just numerics?  If I enter something other than a number, I get this error:

> Failed to convert property value of
>   type java.lang.String to required type
>   java.lang.Integer for property
>   value; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
>   Unable to convert value "A" from type
>   java.lang.String to type
>   java.lang.Integer; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Unable to parse A

I have seen a few posts mention initBinding but I'm not sure how to use it or if it will even help me out.  This has to have been solved before.  Is there any way to ensure that it is a number before it gets binded?

Or, if someone could post the correct messages.properties entry to override this error, that could work for me too.

I tried @Pattern but that doesn't work on ints

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you mentioned, you need a user-friendly message in `messages.properties`. You can use one of the following message codes (with different levels of selectivity):

- `typeMismatch.section.value`
- `typeMismatch.value`
- `typeMismatch.int`
- `typeMismatch`

Also, when you don't know message code, you can simply print the `BindingResult` - its `toString()` returns the full description of the binding errors.

Comment: Can you explain it more detailed?

Comment: More details on the correct location of messages.properties and declaring it in the .xml config files in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540300/spring-3-0-mvc-seems-to-be-ignoring-messages-properties

Comment: there seems to be a circular reference here, this answer points to an answer (for more explanation) which points back to this answer!