# spring mvc annotation validation integer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have an object.

```
public class MyObject
{
   ....
   @Column(name = "a_number") @NotNull @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER) @Min(1)
   private Integer aNumber;
   ...
   //getters and setters
}
```

In my controller I have @Valid annotation on my object being posted. I do have validation working on all my other fields in the class (their all Strings) except this number.  If I enter a number from my form it works fine and if I violate the @Min(1) it also gives me the correct validation error.  My problem however is that if you enter a string instead of a number it throw a NumberFormatException.

I've seen many examples of Integer and validation but no one accounts for if you enter a string into the form being posted.  Do I need to do the validation else where? Javascript?  I would like a solution that falls in line with the rest of spring validation so I could use this in other classes.  I would just like an error stating it must be numeric.  Also I tried using the @Pattern annotation but apparently thats just for strings.

Suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082924/jsr-303-type-checking-before-binding

Comment: Thanks!! Worked pefect!  Your post never showed up in my searches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the following to your file which controls your error messages (these are the generic ones it looks for in the case of a type mismatch:

```
typeMismatch.commandObjectName.aNumber=You have entered an invalid number for ...
typeMismatch.aNumber=You have entered an invalid number for ...
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=You have input a non-numeric value into a field expecting a number...
typeMismatch=You have entered incorrect data on this page.  Please fix (Catches all not found)
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who did not get the idea right here is what to do in `spring 4.2.0`.
Create a file name `messages.properties` in `WEB-INF > classes` folder. And put the above type mismatch messages in that file.
In spring configuration or `servlet.xml` file create the following bean.

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<beans:property name="basename" value="messages"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And for your model attribute like `private Integer aNumber;` in the question along with other validation rules this rule is also applied for type mismatch conversion. You will get your desired message in this.

```
<form:errors path="aNumber"></form:errors>
```

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Still relevant, so I'll add the programmatical approach of **message source bean** definition:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```