# How to restrict a user to enter numerics in a Integer field with help of annotations?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I need to restrain a user to enter numeric values in a jsp field.On failure it should give relevant message.This is my current declaration:

```
@NotNull  
@Column(value="userId")  
private Long userId;
```

I need to know what more annotations do i need to add, to get my desired result without changing data type of the field.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082924/jsr-303-type-checking-before-binding

Answer (score 4):

**Hibernate**

@Range - Check if the value is between min and max

Example

```
    @Range(min=1, max=1000)
```

@Pattern - Check if the property match the regular expression given a match flag
@Pattern(regex="regexp", flag=) or @Patterns( {@Pattern(...)} )

Example

```
    @Pattern(regex = "[0-9]+")
```

**Spring**

@RegExp - Check if the property match the regular expression given a match flag

Example

```
     @RegExp("[0-9]+")
```

Comment: Note the javadoc for `@Pattern`: `The annotated {@code CharSequence} must match the specified regular expression.` It's useless on `Long`.

Comment: @Narendra No, an `Integer` or `Long` field doesn't match a regular expression.

Comment: It works like charm on String fields..But i want to stick on taking my field as Long only.It will be a last resort were i took values in String field and later dumping values in Db as Long after exacting there values from String. :/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that would be done on the validation level.

When you enter something in a form and you submit that form, the browser will send an HTTP request with your `<input>` fields serialized and sent as request parameters. Spring then, based on the data type of your bean's field, tries to convert from a `String` request parameter value to a `Long` type. If it can't do that because the String is not a `Long`, it will throw exceptions (`NumberFormatException`) and respond with a 400 error code.

You can validate this on the (HTML5) client side with

```
<input name="userId" type="number">
```

Or use

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

if you don't want decimal numbers.

Comment: I tried it but sill it prints error on screen:   Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Long for property phoneNumber; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aa"   ... I want to provide a personal message for it.How's that possible.I tried using @Numberformat annotation

Comment: Is there any way to provide custom messasg to the above error?

Comment: @Narendra No, because we aren't using validation with `@Valid` here.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis--Thanks for your replies...It worked somehow after getting to know the proper error message to use in proerty file...previously i was using 'Pojo.attribute[property]="message" '  in my message file....but for such issues... i found this link quiet helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082924/jsr-303-type-checking-before-binding  I printed the BindingResult and tried few combination...and it worked